# Antonym for "derived"/"derivative"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Suppose an idea or an artistic work A is derived from another idea or work B. We would call A the "derivative" or the "derived". What would we call B?

I looked for [antonyms of derived on thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/derived) <sup>*</sup> and couldn't find any.

<sub>* - although I'm really looking more for the *converse* of derivative rather than the *opposite* of it.</sub>

Comment: Could you say more specifically how you define derivative or derivation? What factors determine if something is or isn't derived from something else?

Comment: I agree, I think a clarification of "derivative" would help in this case. Particularly because there's also a [legal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work) of derivative work.

Comment: You could go with *integral* </joke>

Comment: @mbomb007 that sure seems like the [antiderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative)..

Comment: I think what you meant was "corollary" or "partner" and not "antonym". An antonym of "derivative" is "unique" or "fresh".

Comment: @IanMacDonald: I think you meant to say "converse" rather than "corollary".

Comment: @IanMacDonald "unique" and "fresh" are adjectives. The OP is looking for antonym of the noun.

Comment: Am I the only one who finds it odd that the OP uses A (the derivative) before B (the original)

Comment: When a word request attracts a long list of ideas, that is a clear signal that either the criteria are unclear or the question is more of a poll or request for a list of things, neither of which are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model.

Comment: @MetaEd works on [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/big-list/info) and [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/big-list/info) though..

Comment: @MetaEd Or that neither the asker nor the answerers have googled (enough).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider **underlying**

> In copyright law, a derivative work is an expressive creation that includes major copyright-protected elements of an original, previously created first work (the **underlying** work). The derivative work becomes a second, separate work independent in form from the first.

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work

Comment: This is about art, not copyright laws....

Comment: @Lambie I understand that. Just because the quote references copyright law, doesn't mean it's not applicable to art in general. I tried to provide an alternative to "original", which OP didn't like. If you can think of a more suitable word, please let us know.

Comment: Well, presumably, we are dealing with two separate people...underlying makes me think of palimpsests. However,if there is only one.....maybe. :)

Answer (score 32):

I think the term you're looking for is **[original](http://www.gallery-orange.com/a-101-on-art-basics-what-is-original-art/)** (not the adjective, but the noun):

> “Original” quite simply means a unique one-off piece or small edition hand-pulled print from the artists own hand i.e an oil, acrylic, watercolor painting, etching or a drawing  (i.e. not a machine driven process like a giclee).

[Additional definition](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-an-original-artwork-and-a-reproduction-of-it):

> When an artist creates a unique artwork, that is an original. That original may be a painting of some kind, or a sculpture, or a performance work, or one of many other kinds of media.

Usage:

> Is that an original Picasso? That must be worth millions.

Possible response to demonstrate the contrast between the two terms:

> No, it's merely a derivative. You can tell by the careless brushstrokes here.

Note that the terms **derived** (or, alternatively, derivative) and **original (work)** are also [used in the legal context of copyright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work):

> Most countries' legal systems seek to protect both **original and derivative works**. They grant authors the right to impede or otherwise control their integrity and the author's commercial interests. Derivative works and their authors benefit in turn from the full protection of copyright without prejudicing the rights of the original work's author.

Comment: So, this is not so bad, but it doesn't imply the existence of the derived work. It could imply there are copies, or forgeries; while if say "A is a derivative piece" it's obviously what has happened.

Comment: @einpoklum Hmm, not sure what you mean. Could you clarify?

Comment: If A and B are works. B is the Original of A, then A is... you can't say. That is, you can't know that A is a derivative of A, it might be a copy of A, or a forgery of A.

Comment: The OP has said B derives from A. Ergo, A is the original. Forgeries and copies are not implied in the question.

Comment: @Lambie - einpoklum IS the OP... 
Also, your statement does not follow. A could have multiple parent works; a mashup for example. In that case you can still say that B derives from A, but not that A is the original B.

Comment: @ZachP Ok, fine. But I am saying that if one thing derives from another as asked in the question, we are only dealing with two things. Not a bunch of 'em.  It's a "top-level" question, not a drilled-down one.

Comment: I don't think the word we're looking for has to necessarily imply the existence of a derived work. [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work) on derivative work has an interesting paragraph using both terms in contrast: "Most countries' legal systems seek to protect both original and derivative works.[1] They grant authors the right to impede or otherwise control their integrity and the author's commercial interests. Derivative works and their authors benefit in turn from the full protection of copyright without prejudicing the rights of the original work's author."

Comment: Of course, that's specifically about the *legal* definition of "derivative work", so a clearer definition would probably help.

Comment: In some contexts, the word **origin** might be an option, too, especially if the A is more loosely based on B i.e. sculpture based on painting.

Comment: @AleksandrH - Suggest you add your "[This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work)" comment quote to your answer; it helps to broaden your answer away from 'just' art.

Comment: @NigelTouch Good suggestion, added.

Answer (score 30):

The derivative is derived from a ***source***.

ODO:

> **[derivative](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/derivative)**
>   *NOUN*
>   [**1**] Something which is based on another ***source***.
>
> ‘He related the ornament, as we do today to the art of such insular
>   manuscripts as the Book of Kells and the Book of Durrow; indeed, he
>   saw Pictish art as derivative from these sources.’
>
> **[source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/source)**
>   *NOUN*
>   [**1**] A place, person, or thing from which something originates or can be obtained.
>
> ‘mackerel is a good source of fish oil’

Comment: Yes, if indeed the OP meant derived.

Answer (score 12):

**Inspiration**, A is inspired by B, or B was an inspiration for A. According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inspiration):

> someone or something that gives you ideas for doing something

Attribution: definition of “inspiration” from the Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary © Cambridge University Press

Comment: Your inspirations as an author are much wider than a work you're deriving from. Tolkien was [inspired by Nordic mythology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._R._R._Tolkien's_influences), but you can't say the Lord of the Rings is a derivative work of any Norse mythological text.

Comment: @einpoklum You cannot dismiss this answer with just an example, unless you provided more details about what you mean by "derived" in your question. You definitely can use "inspiration" to mean (one of) the source of another work of art. It heavily depends on the context. You used A and B in your question, but without knowing exactly (or more precisely) what A and B are, this is a good answer.

Comment: @einpoklum For example, take the original [film about count Dracula with Bela Lugosi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracula_(1931_English-language_film)): it can be said (I'm not arguing whether that's true or not, beware, but only that it can be linguistically correct) that the more recent film ["Bram Stoker's Dracula"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bram_Stoker%27s_Dracula) was inspired by the first, so the first can be the inspiration for the second.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati: I haven't dismissed it, I've just made a comment.

Answer (score 8):

**Integrated/Integral**

The literal opposite to a derivative is an integral in math and the same is true in the English language.

The OED defines ["derived"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/50614?rskey=v1ZxBK&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) as:

> Drawn, obtained, descended, or deduced from a source.

While ["integrated"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/97354?rskey=PbauaO&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) is:

> Combined into a whole; united; undivided.

I don't think it's the word you're looking for, as it's not a name for B in your example, but it's worth noting that this would be the antonym of derived/derivative.

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with **[progenitor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/progenitor)**:

> a : an ancestor in the direct line : forefather
>
> b : a biologically ancestral form

Usage:

> His work was thought to be the progenitor of all modern works of art.

Comment: Don't you use that only for people/active agents?

Comment: By strict definition I believe the word is strictly biological but I also believe the feel of the word carries enough implication to get the point across. By that same interpretation, I'd argue that the work itself could be an active agent in encouraging others to derive, i.e. an inspirational work.

Comment: Works of art do not have progenitors, except metaphorically, and then it would mean the original artist who created it.

Comment: @Lambie - see my comment directly above.

Comment: There can be no progeny if there's no progenitor. +1

Comment: This word makes me think of ‘‘prototype’’.

Answer (score 4):

Seminal ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seminal))

> containing or contributing the seeds of later development

Seed ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seed))

> a source of development or growth

Comment: The makings of a good answer but desperately needs a link to a reference. Up-voted pending an edit and sorting out a noun rather than an adjective.

Comment: seminal is an adjective. You don't say this work derives from that seminal.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the context, you could also use **[genesis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genesis)**:

> the origin or coming into being of something

Usage:

> Aasimov's "I, Robot" was the genesis for modern AI sci-fi

Although, this also carries a bit of connotation of continued works meaning it is probably less appropriate when only A and B exist, but would work great when A begat B begat C begat D and etc.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we should go back to the meaning of **derivation**, or its [derivation](https://www.etymonline.com/word/derive) (Romance *de-ripare* or *de-rivare*, ultimately Latin *de* + *rivus*, "going down the river").

Asking for an antonym is asking: "where does the object come from"? From all these answers, it is obvious that there could be as many legimate **antonyms** for "derived" or "derivative" as there are different possible starting points in a derivation processes (origin, underlying, original, template, mould, integral, etc.).

If we want a general, blanket concept, we might have to look in the direction... of **upstream** (up + stream):

> Being or moving closer to the source of a stream; in the direction
>   opposite to that of the current: upstream traffic; an upstream dam ([American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=upstream))

It could be the **upstream**, to coin a term.

Note that if we go all the way back to the origin point of a stream, the fountainhead is the **source** (in an [etymological sense](https://www.etymonline.com/word/source), from Latin *surgere* "to spring").

The **source point** (for the stream) or the **starting point** ("a place to start", [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/starting%20point)) might also answer the question, though not as expressive as all the specialized alternatives already proposed. Yet the a *source point* might no be general enough: an object might be derived from *several* others. In which case you might have to deal with *components*, *elements*, *atoms*, *raw materials* etc. At which point we might get into mathematical or technical jargon, probably too abstract for daily conversation (a *source set*)?

Comment: So: "B is the upstream of A"? Hmm, not bad. I think I'll take it.

Comment: To be fair, I don't think you'd hear anyone say, "X piece of art is the upstream of all these derived works." Of course, if you'd like to use that, it's entirely up to you. Nothing wrong with coining a new term/usage, as long as your readers understand what you meant.

Comment: To be fair, I haven't either. But if that suits the need in the particular case (especially if it is a technical usage), it might be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

The inspiration; The original piece which emerged by it's predecessor's vision.

Comment: Avoid using comments for a purpose other than improving the post they are attached to. For example, comments can be used to ask the author for clarification, point out problems, or suggest changes. Please do not use comments for debate. A better place for debate or free-wheeling discussion is our [chat] (or, when one exists, the chatroom attached to the post itself). Remember to keep it friendly/respectful. See: “[Be Nice – Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)”.

Answer (score 1):

**[parent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/parent)** (ODOL)
noun

> **1.3** A source or origin of a smaller or less important part.
>   as modifier ‘some of the whetstones have been transported up to 400 km from the parent rock’
>
> **1.2** An animal or plant from which new ones are derived.
>   ‘stems will root down, creating a new crown near the parent’

cf. *parent class* vs. *derived class*

Answer (score 0):

On could never guess at the meaning of that word because it is underived from any known language from which the English language is related. That seems to be the simplest way to express that thought with just one word.

Comment: What "one word"?

Answer (score 0):

The OP states in a comment to one of the answers that the answer should imply the existence of one or more pieces of derivative work.

One idiom that necessarily implies the existence of derivatives or knockoffs is **"[the real McCoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_real_McCoy):"**

> "The real McCoy" is an idiom and metaphor used in much of the English-speaking world to mean "the real thing" or "the genuine article", e.g. "he's the real McCoy".

The above definition shows that there are other ways of saying this, such as **"the genuine article"**.

(EDIT) I missed the tag "single-word-requests" until I went back and looked so let me know if I need to get rid of this answer.